# How to eager load lazy-loading properties/components with NHibernate Criteria API?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a lazy-loading property (component) in one of my entity classes. In `HQL` I can write "fetch all properties" to eagerly load it.

Can I do the same with Criteria API? I tried `criteria.SetFetchMode("PropertyName", FetchMode.Eager)` but is not working. I am using `NHibernate 3.1 GA`

Comment: I'd expect what you've got to work, but I usually specify join or select for the FetchMode.  Is it not loading anything on the component, or is it loading some but not all?

I think class definition and mappings would help here.